# Two Spinners 50% of RelativeLayout width - no nasted LinerLayouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-spinner

I have such layout, but can't get those 2 `spinner` to get 50% of my `RelativeLayout`(`rs_branches` and `rs_education`). I tried to adjust `layout_width` to other values, but didn't help. Any suggestions?

I don't want to use nested `LinerLayouts`, because I will need to expand the second `ScrollView` in similar way, as this one filled.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/rs_sv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/rs_name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/rs_question_hint" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/rs_dates"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/rs_name"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rs_times"
                />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@id/rs_times"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/rs_name"
                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/rs_times"
                android:text="@string/rs_simple_search" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/rs_sv2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <!-- ... -->

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if you use two spinners inside a linear layout you will get the desired result

Comment: Yes, but if I use 6 spinners, 2 lists (l_width:fill_parent), 2 radioGroups, which should be placed aside each other in pairs like: spiner1 | spiner2 \n, then it's better to use Relative. And I design my app for And 4.1+, and as I read on http://developer.android.com it's recommended to use RelativeLayouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get what you mean :

> "I don't want to use nested LinerLayouts, because I will need to
>   expand the second ScrollView in similar way, as this one filled."

The solution with a linearLayout would be :

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/rs_name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/rs_question_hint" />

            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_below="@id/rs_name" >

                 <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/rs_dates"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                  />

                 <Spinner
                    android:id="@id/rs_times"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                  />
              </LinearLayout>

              ...
```

And here is a solution without adding a **LinearLayout** :

(align to center of the relativeLayout by adding an empty view with 'centerHorizontal="true"' )

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/rs_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/rs_question_hint" />
        <View
             android:id="@+id/rs_centered" 
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/rs_dates"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/rs_name"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rs_centered"
            />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@id/rs_times"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rs_centered"
            android:layout_below="@id/rs_name"
            />
```

It should work,  let  me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the spinner's width in java code. Just get the screen width and set get 50% of it.
You should do this in method `Activity.onCreate()`